# WCF Dataservices and OData

Tags: wcf, odata

Could someone please explain the difference? From what I understand, I could expose my data directly using WCF data services or expose it using OData. OData is a more universal protocol?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937697.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393623/OData-Services

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OData is the **protocol specification / standard** - how to query, what operators to use on the URL etc.

WCF Data Services is the **.NET/WCF implementation** of that protocol / standard.

So you cannot expose your data using OData - it's not a product or a code base you can use.

However, you can do so using WCF Data Services which is based on the OData protocol/standard.

Comment: Thanks. Can WCF be used to explose other protocol specifications other than OData?

Comment: WCF can use SOAP or REST for its communication - but those aren't quite the same sort of protocols as OData. I'm not really sure there are any other protocols similar to OData - and if there are, I would not be aware of any WCF implementations thereof.